# How to know which process(stat: T) is attached by gdb?

Tags: process, gdb

When a process is attached by gdb, the stat of the process is "T", like:

```
root      6507  0.0  0.0  67896   952 ?        Ss   12:01   0:00 /mytest
root      6508  0.0  0.0 156472  7120 ?        Sl   12:01   0:00 /mytest
root     26994  0.0  0.0  67896   956 ?        Ss   19:59   0:00 /mytest
root     26995  0.0  0.0 156460  7116 ?        Tl   19:59   0:00 /mytest
root     27833  0.0  0.0  97972 24564 pts/2    S+   20:00   0:00 gdb /mytest
```

From the above, 26995 may be debuging. How can I know 26995 is debug or not? Or can I know which process is attached by gdb(27833)

pstree -p 27833  --- show gdb(27833)

**Another question: How to know a process(stat: T) is attached by which gdb(PID)?**
In most siduation, I am not the peoson who is debuging the process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `T` in `ps` output stands for "being ptrace()d". So that process (26995) is being traced by *something*. That something is most often either `GDB`, or `strace`.

So yes, if you know that you are only running `GDB` and not `strace`, and if you see a single process in `T` state, then you know that you are debugging that process.

You could also ask `GDB` which process(es) it is debugging:

```
(gdb) info process
(gdb) info inferior
```

**Update**
As Matthew Slattery correctly noted, `T` just means the process is stopped, and not that it is being `ptrace()d`.

So a better solution is to do this:

```
 grep '^TracerPid:' /proc/*/status | grep -v ':.0'
 /proc/7657/status:TracerPid:    31069
```

From above output you can tell that process 7657 is being traced by process 31069. This answers both "which process is being debugger" and "which debugger is debugging what".

Comment: `T` just means "stopped", not necessarily "being ptrace()d".  For example, try `sleep 10000`, press Ctrl-Z, then `ps ux | grep sleep`.

Comment: In GDB 7.8, `info process` does not exist anymore. Both `info proc` or `info program` show PID.

Answer (score 6):

/proc file system is a telent design of Linux. Many process real-time information can be found from **/proc/{PID}/**.

> Another question: How to know a process(stat: T) is attached by which
>   gdb(PID)? In most siduation, I am not the peoson who is debuging the
>   process.

For this question, we can check /proc/{PID}/status file to get the answer.

```
root     14616  0.0  0.0 36152  908 ?        Ss   Jun28   0:00 /mytest
root     14617  0.5  0.0 106192 7648 ?       Sl   Jun28 112:45 /mytest
tachyon   2683  0.0  0.0 36132 1008 ?        Ss   11:22   0:00 /mytest
tachyon   4276  0.0  0.0 76152 20728 pts/42  S+   11:22   0:00 gdb /mytest
tachyon   2684  0.0  0.0 106136 7140 ?       Tl   11:22   0:00 /mytest
```

host1-8>cat /proc/2684/status

```
Name:   mytest
State:  T (tracing stop)
SleepAVG:       88%
Tgid:   2684
Pid:    2684
PPid:   2683
TracerPid:      4276
.......
```

Thus we know 2684 is debug by process 4276.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out this info from `ps axf` output.

```
 1357 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
 1935 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/0
 1994 pts/0    Ss     0:00      \_ -bash
 2237 pts/0    T      0:00          \_ gdb /bin/ls
 2242 pts/0    T      0:00          |   \_ /bin/ls
 2243 pts/0    R+     0:00          \_ ps axf
```

Here process 2242 is being debuged by gdb process 2237.