# How to find who is tracing my process?

Tags: linux, trace

On linux, my process is in attached status, it's attached by annother guy.
How to find who is debuging my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in [proc file system](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html). Look at TracerPid entry in /proc/somepid/status. See also [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659308/how-to-know-which-processstat-t-is-attached-by-gdb).