# How to debug a multithreaded hung process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

A multithreaded application hangs and it is not responding to any commands. I have tried following things without luck:

1. Attach a process to gdb (error: (gdb) attach 6026
                                  Attaching to process 6026
                                  ptrace: Operation not permitted.)
2. gstack (gstack just hangs like that)

Is there any good way to debug this process?

Comment: Are you trying to attach as root, or as the user that created the process, or as some other user?  Have you tried running the program from gdb before it gets to the point where it hangs?

Comment: @Jonatha Leffler I ran that process in root and I used the same id to attach the process in gdb. This is not foreground process, this a daemon process.

Comment: OK; if it runs as root and you are trying to run gdb as root, then it isn't a simple matter of privileges (but it may be a complex one).  On the whole, what I'd do is start the daemon in gdb, using options such as `set follow-fork-mode` and `set fork-detach-mode`.

Comment: @Jonatha Leffler Thanks for you suggestion, but right now the problem hits at this point. I like to debug this process somehow. This problem may not be reproducible in future right?

Comment: Are you or somebody else already tracing 6026 process? Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6705492/72178) question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all your response. The problem is at kernel level. we used echo t > /proc/sysrq-trigger, which logs the stack of all the running process in /var/log/messages. This stack trace helped to analyze the problem.

From the stack trace, file system posted some waited event on behalf of the application process to other process (which is in defunct state) and waiting for the response indefinitely. Which results in hung state.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely somebody else already tracing this process. To find out who is doing it look at proc file system.

```
cat /proc/6026/status|grep TracerPid
```

Comment: Then the reason is somewhat else